# I have opcode, but not the chip that it runs on. How can I determine what instruction set architecture it is?

Tags: opcode

I have a firmware file that runs on an IOT device and I need to figure out what the firmware file is doing. I assume the file is opcode but I don't know what the architecture of the CPU it is running on is. Is there a way I can determine what the instruction set is just based on the code?

Thank you!

Here is a snippet of start of the file:

```
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
```

Answer (score 0):

No, sadly there isn't. The only way to do this would be if the file had some sort of metadata (as in the case of ELF and PE files).